# Animation in UWP

Tags: uwp

I am trying to make a `TextBlock` `Fade In` and `Fade Out` in a `UWP` automatically. I tried searching for the same but didn't found any samples or a proper documentation for the same. Is is possible to add animation, if yes please help me with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

For a ready-made solution, I think you can use the [Fade animation extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.animations.animationextensions.fade?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet)
of [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.animations?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet)

If yor wish a preview , install the *Windows Community Toolkit Sample App* . This app will also show you how to use a lot of cool extensions out of the box so that you don't have to create yourself.